# HTML5 and facebook integration

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, html

i am having a rather unusual and annoying error. Before i show code let me explain. I am designing a computer game through HTML 5 and JavaScript, with the intention of uploading the game to facebook on behalf of my employer. I have been working hard on the game and only today have decided to upload the game to facebook to test her out. However many of the images that i have do not display on screen. I have being regularly testing me game through various browsers and the game works fine. I have uploaded the game to a web host that i am subscribed to and that works fine as well. However after copying the html file, inputting the php code and uploading it to my companies host only a few images work as opposed to the rest.
I have checked the image directory that i store images, all the images are there. I did notice something though. I have 3 canvas's, each layered on top of each, in the JavaScript file they are :

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("background");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvas1 = document.getElementById("enemyCanvas");
var context = canvas1.getContext("2d");

var canvas2 = document.getElementById("introCanvas");
var context1 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
```

the images that do not work are as follows
player

```
var drawPlayer = function() {
    if (playerReady) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(player.x, player.y);
        ctx.drawImage(sprite,0,481,65,59, -(playerImage.width / 2), -34,65,65);
        ctx.restore();
    }
};
```

the text for gameOver (when you die)

```
var setGameOverText = function() {
    button.innerHTML = "RESTART";
    backTrack.pause();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasX, canvasY);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasX, canvasY);
    context1.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0, 0)";
    context1.textBaseline = "top";
    context1.font = "20px Helvetica";
    context1.fillText("You have Died, it's game over for you!", 100, 80);
    context1.fillText("Score: " + kills, 200, 220);
    context1.fillText("press the button to restart", 140, 360);
    reset();
    context1.font = "12px Helvetica";
};
```

the number of lives (this is 2 different images, one is a glowing text image and the other is an image of a heart)

```
var setHealthImages = function() {

    var healthImg = new Image();
    healthImg.src = "images/health.png";
    var ix = 423;
    var iy = 524;

    for(i = 0; i < numOfLives; i++) {
        ctx.drawImage(healthImg, ix, iy);
        ix = ix + 20;
    }
};
```

upgrade icons for damage and speed

```
context1.drawImage(speedUpgradeImage, 190,198);
context1.drawImage(damageUpgradeImage, 190,250);
```

the below code is the PHP/html file excluding app id key, security key and game title

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require 'server/fb-php-sdk/facebook.php';

    $app_id = 'leaving blank here';
    $app_secret = 'leaving blank here';
    $app_namespace = 'leaving blank here';
    $app_url = 'https://apps.facebook.com/' . $app_namespace . '/';
    $scope = 'email,publish_actions';

    // Init the Facebook SDK
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
         'appId'  => $app_id,
         'secret' => $app_secret,
));

// Get the current user
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// If the user has not installed the app, redirect them to the Login Dialog
if (!$user) {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => $scope,
        'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
        ));

        print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\'</script>');
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>XXX</title>
</head>



<body>



<canvas id="background" width="500" height="600" z-index="0">
Your browser does not support canvas. Please try again with a different browser.
</canvas>
<canvas id="enemyCanvas" width="501" height="601" z-index="1">
Your browser does not support canvas. Please try again with a different browser.
</canvas>
<canvas id="introCanvas" width="501" height="601" z-index="2">
Your browser does not support canvas. Please try again with a different browser.
</canvas>
<div id="button"><strong>PLAY GAME</strong></div>
<div id="button1"><strong>INSTRUCTIONS</strong></div>
<div id="LevelUpSpeedButton"><strong></strong></div>
<div id="LevelUpDamageButton"><strong></strong></div>
<div id="SoundButton"></div>
<div id="iframe">
<iframe src="#" height="600" width="240" seamless></iframe>
</div>

<script src="Game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just to reiterate a few points, the images are correctly located. The game works off facebook both on my own server host and just off my pc running locally. I failed to mention that they work as html, the only time the game was tested with the PHP was when i uploaded it to facebook and no the game is not visible to the facebook community only myself and some guy that works in the company, as an developer.

Help is always appreciated.

Comment: If you don’t show us a live example. you will have to start debugging yourself.

Comment: sorry for taking so long to reply but, i am not entirely confident in posting a link to my employers hosting address nor the series of directory files that also includes my real name, i know yeah i have trust issues, i am an intern for this company i don't want to be given details about my company without their permission especially since it gives details of who hosts their websites and the layout of the directory system. Aside from that i have been doing some messing about in my code and may have found a possible solution.

Comment: As most know there is two ways to create a function, function name() or var name = function() we also know that when being loaded the var name is done first, or at least this is my interpretation, which would suggest to me that these functions are asking to draw images that have not been initialised yet, would this be correct?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for taking so long to respond to my own question, but it would seem that i have found the solution myself. In a response above i mentioned that there are two way you can create a function

```
var drawPlayerImage = function(){
ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
}
or 
function drawPlayerImage(){
....
}
```

the way you write your functions determines which function gets loaded first. the first function is assigning a variable to an anonymous function and it gets called at the beginning (forgive me if this explanation is not fully accurate).
the reason why i was getting missing graphics was the result of using a combination between var draw = func and function draw styles. To go into a bit more depth, I declare the images and initialize them near the top of my code and since some of the functions are being used first the images are not actually being loaded up before they are being used. This means that servers are unable to load the images.

After changing the function declarations from var drawPlayerImage to function drawPlayerImage the images started showing up on Internet Explorer and Chrome, but not FireFox, this is due to the fact that on Firefox the older (cached) version of the JavaScript file is being used as opposed to the new version which was also why it took 24 hours to solve.

So if there is anything the community can take away from this lesson it is these gems.
Know the difference between :

```
var functionName = function(){..}
```

and

```
function functionName(){..}
```

as well as remember to clear your cache if changes to your code seem to work elsewhere.